# How to change menu language in Draw.io?

Tags: localization, app.diagrams.net

I'm currently in Brazil and using Window 8 in English. But looks like Draw.io decide to use my ip to define the language of menus.

The translation is good but I really prefer in English since all help is easier in English.

Is it possible to change language to English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to change the language in [Diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net/) (formerly Draw.io).

The method differs depending if you want the change to be remembered for future visits or only for the current session.

For a permanent change, the instructions are different depending if your browser is accessing the **Desktop** or **Mobile** version of the site. Also note that custom language setting is stored in a cookie and if deleted, the language will revert.

### Desktop Mode (Permanent)

Under the **`Extras Menu`** ,  select **`Language`** then  **`English`**
[image]

### Mobile Mode (Permanent)

Under the **`Meatball Menu`** ,  select **`Settings`** then **`Language`** then  **`English`**
[image]

### URL Edit (Temporary)

You can alternatively append `?lang=en` to the URL (`https://app.diagrams.net/?lang=en`) in both **Desktop** and **Mobile** which will override the current language setting for that session.  The setting is temporary and you will need to modify the URL each time you visit.

Comment: Your querystring worked for me.

Comment: @hydra Would it be possible to change your answer to include the details in mine? The language menu has been in for about 18 months, but a google search tends to show your answer first and people think it can't be done. If you update yours, I'll just delete mine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change the language in draw.io by entering it in the preferences file.
Access to the file via Extra's > configuration > Preferences.

it shows a json structure, with language being the first element.

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "configVersion": null,
  "customFonts": [],
  ...
}
```

By default, the value is an empty string, setting a language code and applying makes the system use that language for future sessions. After a Refresh the browser page, the selected language is used.

Answer (score 1):

With the initial language draw.io uses the language of the browser installation, which can vary from the OS language setting. There is no processing of IP addresses, draw.io is a client-side app.

There is an option under the extras menu:

[image: Screenshot of app.diagrams.net with the extras menu expanded in french language setting]

You need to refresh the page for the language change to take effect. Note that you also need cookies to be enabled for the setting to persist.

Comment: This is strange. My Os is in english and my browser too. Actually I have both Portuguese and English but the one I was using was English. Right now I tried again and it displayed in Portuguese even my browser been set to English before access that site.

Comment: Different browsers offer different values for the value we read. For IE we use the "userLanguage" value and for other browsers the "language" value. We know this isn't the best solution for an end-user application, it's like this because it originally wasn't designed to be end-user. But, as I say, when the change goes in you'll only need to set the language once and then it'll be remembered.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont see the world icon anywhere

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: [Hydra's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42786/) improved per [your comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/how-to-change-menu-language-in-draw-io/170350#comment62779_42786)